# How to vlookup values in another sheet same workbook and return adjacent columns

Tags: gs-vlookup

I have tried this formula but it could not work.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="","",VLOOKUP(A2:A,Sheet2$A$2:$F,2)))`

The link to my google sheets file is:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17v3cSVPdKnaKiuOKP1-A68_WUvSm4Gm4vj4yfKsjJzc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this formula

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="","",(VLOOKUP($A$2:A,Sheet2!$A$2:$G,2,FALSE))))`